# Pop an element from a list in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary where for each key there is a corresponding list. I am trying to create a function that receives the name of a key then removes and returns the first element in the corresponding list. However, I am having some trouble doing this. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
d = {'one': [1, 2, 3], 'two': [4, 5, 6]}

def get_item(item_name):
    return d.pop(item_name[0])

get_item('two')

# Expected output: 4
```

Comment: You can assert that item_name[0] == 't' Does that give you a clue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try it like this:

```
def get_item(item_name):
    return d[item_name].pop()
```

`d[item_name]` gets you the list and then `.pop()` pops an item out

Answer (score 0):

````
    def epic(d, key, element):
        if key in d and element in d[key]:
        d[key].remove(element)
        print(f"Deleted {element} from the list associated with key '{key}'")
        print(f'deleted element: {element}')
    else:
        print(f"Element {element} not found in the list associated with key '{key}'")    

epic(d, 'two', 4)    ```
````